# Creating Words Dictionary and Mapping to other languages

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I am creating an app, where user can search in multiple languages. Let's say I have a website which host a very big novel. may be consisting of thousands of para graphs. some where between 20,000 to 30,000 para graphs.

A user can read the novel in multiple languages. He can search in multiple languages. For example he searches "LOVE" in English, I will show him all the paragraphs containing "LOVE" in them.

Now, if user switches to French, and searches "Amour" (French for Love), I will show him all paragraphs containing "Amour" in them.

I can do it by creating two versions of the novel, one in french and other in English. Indeed, I will have the translations. But, when user is reading the novel I will give him an option to click on any word and see it's translation to other languages. In this case, if he is reading in English, I will show him translation of that particular word in French and vise versa.

This means I want to keep a word to word mapping between different languages.

One way of doing is to create a map my self, which is a lot of work. another way could be some API calls, for example Google Translator. 
Can you suggest best approach? Any existing API?
Some Google Terms to go into the right direction for this task would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch can be good solution to your problem.

1. Simply index your content in their native language (index it well)
2. Then you can use Elasticsearch Phonetic Plugin for multi-lingual search (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic.html)

for the other part, where you want to do word by word translation, I think google translate or other translation api can be integrated or maybe elasticsearch as well.

I hope this helps.